# Why is network-byte-order defined to be big-endian?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, endianness, tcp

As written in the heading, my question is, why does **TCP/IP** use big endian encoding when transmitting data and not the alternative little-endian scheme?

Comment: despite the fact that it has been closed down, this page was quite helpful

Comment: From [this product guide](https://www.wolfvision.com/wolf/commands_cynap_wolfvision/protocol_command.htm),  under the **Big Endian** link: *Networks generally use big-endian order, and thus it is called network order when sending information over a network in a common format. The telephone network, historically and presently, uses a big-endian order; doing so allows routing while a telephone number is being composed. [...]* Presumably the early computer networks relied on the telephone networks of the day, and the rest is history...

Comment: At the time the "standard" was created the majority of the servers were big-endian. Nowadays it is the opposite, but we cannot change the TCP/IP protocol due to backwards compatibility. New protocols can use little-endian though

Comment: ...but if you are thinking of using little-endian in your shiny-new network protocol, [this should interest you](https://www.cnn.com/TECH/space/9909/30/mars.metric/) - humans switching between fundamentally-different formats or systems is a fraught exercise...

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**[RFC1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700)** stated **it must be so**. (and defined network byte order as big-endian).

> The convention in the documentation of Internet Protocols is to
> express numbers in decimal and to picture data in "big-endian" order
> [COHEN].  That is, fields are described left to right, with the most
> significant octet on the left and the least significant octet on the
> right.

The reference they make is to

```
On Holy Wars and a Plea for Peace 
Cohen, D. 
Computer
```

The abstract can be found at [**IEN-137**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/ien/ien137.txt) or on [this IEEE page](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=1667115).

---

**Summary:**

> Which way is chosen does not make too much
> difference.  It is more important to  agree  upon an order than which
> order is agreed upon.

It concludes that both big-endian and little-endian schemes could've been possible. There is no **better/worse** scheme, and either can be used in place of the other as long as it is consistent all across the system/protocol.

Comment: RFC 3232 appears to say "RFC1700 is obsolete" without giving any replacement

Comment: @Anirudh, This "answer" is avoiding the question. The question is asking for the underlying reason why bigendian is chosen instead of the alternative([s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian)). Re "*Which way is chosen does not make too much difference*",, this is false because in reality it matters due to the simple fact that performance matters (and such a standard is entrenched in the very bottom layers of network communications).

Comment: @Pacerier There wouldn't be a difference in terms of performance, which is what the linked paper talks about in detail.

Comment: There is a significant difference. As a lot of network protocol parsers are written in C or a derivative of it for performance reasons, having little endian encoding on an Intel/AMD/little endian computer means a simple casting of a "void *" to a "struct *". If a conversion is needed, "htonl, htons, ntohl, ntohs" needs to be called on each field and inherently creates a copy.