# What is the right order of bytes in a TCP header?

Tags: tcp

I'm trying to encode a TCP header myself, but can't understand what is the right order of bits/octets in it. This is what [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1) says:

```
0                   1                   2                   3
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|          Source Port          |       Destination Port        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|                        Sequence Number                        |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
...
```

This means that `Source Port` should take first two octets and the lowest bit should be in the first octet. This means to me that in order to encode source port 180 I should start my TCP header with these two bytes:

```
B4 00 ...
```

However, all examples I can find tell me to do it the other way around:

```
00 B4 ...
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This means that Source Port should take first two octets

Correct.

> and the lowest bit should be in the first octet.

Incorrect. It doesn't mean that. It doesn't say anything about it.

All multi-byte integers in all IP headers are represented in network byte order, which is big-endian.  This is specified in [RFC 1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700).

Comment: looks like this question is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514614/why-is-network-byte-order-defined-to-be-big-endian