# Are there any advantages to network byte order in a new protocol?

Tags: endianness, cbor

*(I know many people are going to be tempted to close this question; please don't; I'm asking for concrete technical answers, if any exist.)*

"Network byte order" is big-endian for reasons that [cannot be asked on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514614/why-is-network-byte-order-defined-to-be-big-endian). Lots of old protocols use that order and can't be changed but I wonder if there are any technical reasons to choose big endian for a new protocol.

I would think little endian is better, because 99.99% of processors in use are little endian (ARM can technically do both, but in reality it is always set to little endian). So I was surprised to see that CBOR, a relatively recent protocol, uses big endian. Is there an advantage that I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to human factors:  **It is easier to read a multi-byte integer in a hex dump if it is encoded with the most significant byte(s) first.**   For example, the CBOR representation of 0x1234 (4,660) is the byte sequence 19 12 34.   If you are looking for the value 0x1234, it is easier to spot it that way.

TLDR;

I've been in the field for over 40 years now, so there's a lot of history behind this.   Even the definition of a "byte" has changed over that many years, so this may take a bit of an open mind to understand how this evolved.

Dumps of binary information weren't always in bytes, nor hexadecimal.  For example, the PDP-11 (with 16-bit words, and 8-bit bytes) the use of octal notation word-wide dumps was common.  This was useful because of the machine architecture, which inculuded 8 registers, and 8 addressing modes, so machine langugage dumps in octal were easier to decode than hex.

Comment: I don't think people using CBOR (or any other binary protocol) generally decode it by reading raw hex though, so that doesn't seem like a very good reason to require practically every computer in the world to do two pointless endianness swaps.

Comment: You miss my point.   You asked if there were *any technical reasons to choose big endian for a new protocol.*   I'm saying yes, but it doesn't have to do with how protocol decoders operate, it has to do with human factors.   This sort of human factor is still quite technical and relates to human activities needed while adopting new protocols.

Comment: Perhaps you assume that the byte swapping causes a performance hit.   That used to bother me too, but as processors have gotten faster, it bothers me less and less.   At this point, I would be surprised if you could meaningfullly measure any significant application-level performance difference if CBOR were little-endian instead of big-endian.   Generally the speed of gettings bytes in/out of a system will dominate practical performance, not internal processor-level work like byte swapping.

Comment: 36 _is_ evenly dividable by 4 bits. Perhaps you've meant "by 8 bits"?

Comment: @Burt_Harris 36 is evenly divisible by 4 bits, but PDP-10 did use for example 18-bits half-words which aren't

Comment: It seems like my use of 36 bit PDP-10 in the answer may be ill advised, and unrelated to the core point about byte order.   I'll make an edit.

Comment: @Timmmm you'd think so but in the protocols I've been involved with, "easily readable <hexdumps / wireshark logs / ...> was often a prime concern

Comment: Wireshark can decode protocols to easily readable form. That's kind of the whole point! Generally if you're losing time to reading hex dumps the solution is not "change the format so I can read it easier in a hex editor", it's "write a tools so I don't *need* to read it in a hex editor".

Comment: @Timmmm, The decision on 'network byte order' dates back to the 1970s, at least 20 years before Wireshark existed.   I worked on protocol implementations back in the 70's on machines with both byte order conventions, so it makes sense.  I guess now it is mostly just an accepted convention passed on by guys with white beards.

Comment: Right, we're talking about new protocols though. They have no reason to follow the old convention.